# An isometrie $\varphi: S_1\to S_2$ which cannot be extended into distance-preserving map

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples

I'm searching for an example isometrie $\varphi: S_1\to S_2$($S_i$ are regular surfaces) which cannot be extended into distance-preserving maps $F: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$. A reference or hint will help too.

---

\color{gray}{No need the proof of isometrie or disability for extending.}

Comment: What are $S_1$ and $S_2$?  How about a line segment mapping to a curve by an arclength parameterization?  Does this fit your criteria?

Comment: I've edited it, so your example doesn't fit.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari: How about an isometry between a part of the plane and a part of the cylinder? The extrinsic distance are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John gave a (pretty standard) example as a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599573/an-isometrie-varphi-s-1-to-s-2-which-cannot-be-extended-into-distance-preser#comment1266260_599573): the surfaces 
$$\{(x,y,0):0<x<\pi, 0<y<1\}$$ 
and 
$$\{(\cos x,y,\sin x): 0<x<\pi, 0<y<1\}$$ are isometric in their intrinsic metrics, but are not extrinsically isometric.